# How do I turn a string in dot notation into a nested object with a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, split, reduce

I was trying to do this with split and reduce but I can't figure it out.

Here is my string and value

```
const str = "stack.overflow.is.cool"
const value = "Indeed"
```

I would like to turn this into

```
{ stack: 
  { overflow: 
    { is: 
      { cool: indeed }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You mentioned you "were trying to do this"; can you share your previous attempts, so that the community might be able to point out where you might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With map. Also possible with reduce and recursive function..

```js
const str = "stack.overflow.is.cool"
const value = "Indeed"

let obj = {};
let pointer = obj;
str.split('.').map( (key, index, arr) => {
  pointer = (pointer[key] = (index == arr.length - 1? value: {}))
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, ' '));
```

Comment: your answer isn't proper, see I share all test case. please edit your answer also for test case which one i share https://jsfiddle.net/sbzowLxj/